# Ionic / Leaflet - Can't get Tiles 404 Not Found (from cache)

Tags: http-status-code-404, leaflet, ionic-framework, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm locked with an issue that is very odd.
I'm using [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) with [angular-leaflet-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive).
On the previous app, everything worked.

Now on a new app, I'd like to implement a new leaflet map.
I have therefore copied my previous code.

My Issue is that, the leaflet map opens, my markers are created, but

> TILES are not loaded

(I do have internet & internet rights for my app)
Every tile that tries to be loaded failed and gets the following issue :

```
GET http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/18/98891/132985.png 404 (Not Found)
```

As you can see, if direct access to the tile, you can see it on browser.

**Header of each Tile GET request**

```
    GENERAL
      Request URL:http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/18/98892/132984.png
      Request Method:GET
      **Status Code:404 Not Found (from cache)**
    RESPONSE HEADERS
      Client-Via:shouldInterceptRequest
    REQUEST HEADERS
      Provisional headers are shown
      Accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
      User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.1; GT-I9505 Build/LRX22C; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/42.0.2311.137 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

> My feeling is that is it trying to load it from cache instead of
>   directly loading it from the open provider
>   I still can't get what is different between my 2 projects

My other working application has the following header for each tile:

```
GENERAL 
  Remote Address:192.163.219.40:80
  Request URL:http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/18/98818/132892.png
  Request Method:GET
  Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
  view source
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
  Cache-Control:max-age=604800
  Content-Length:3584
  Content-Type:image/png
  Date:Fri, 08 May 2015 13:57:36 GMT
  ETag:"51fb8a7a0f719b211641dca08bf1d76b"
  Expires:Fri, 15 May 2015 13:57:36 GMT
  Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
  Via:1.1 nadder-02.openstreetmap.org:3128 (squid/2.7.STABLE9)
  X-Cache:MISS from nadder-02.openstreetmap.org
  X-Cache-Lookup:MISS from nadder-02.openstreetmap.org:3128
Request Headers
  view source
  Accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
  Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
  Accept-Language:fr-FR,en-US;q=0.8
  Connection:keep-alive
  Host:c.tile.openstreetmap.org
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.1; GT-I9505 Build/LRX22C; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/42.0.2311.137 Mobile Safari/537.36
  X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:01BAB1E4-1122-4CEF-AC90-BDE2C1113EF4
  X-Requested-With:com.myapp.myapp
```

*AngularJS configuration*

Cache is disabled.

```
$httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;
```

I also tried the following additive as HTTP TILE LOADING are get (not successful)

```
  //initialize get if not there
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};    
    }    
//disable IE ajax request caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT';
    // extra
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get.Pragma = 'no-cache';
```

*HTML Creation of leaflet directive*

```
  <div data-tap-disabled="true" style="height: 90%; {{iosPlatform ? 'top:10%; position:relative' : ''}}">
    <leaflet id="map" defaults="defaults" center="center"
    bounds="bounds" event-broadcast="events" markers="markers"
    height="100%" width="100%" class="animation" layers="layers"></leaflet>

  </div>
```

*AngularJS Code*

```
angular.extend($scope, {
            center: {
                lat: -2.6273,
                lng: -44.1932,
                zoom: 18
            },
            markers: {},
            defaults: {
                scrollWheelZoom: true
            },
            bounds: {
                southWest: {
                    lat: -2.628074696286876,
                    lng: -44.19960723876953125,
                },
                northEast: {
                    lat: -2.629410211532874,
                    lng: -44.19617401123046874,
                }
            },
            events: {
                map: {
                    enable: ['popupopen'],
                    logic: 'emit'
                }
            },
            tiles: {
                url: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                options: {
                    attribution: ''
                }
            },
            layers: {
                "baselayers": {
                    "osm": {
                        "name": "Cidade",
                        "url": "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                        "type": "xyz",
                        "layerParams": {},
                        "layerOptions": {}

                    }


                },
                overlays: {

                }
            },
            controls: {}
        });
```

When I open my map, I do call the following function :

```
 $scope.getMyMap = function() {
        var d = $q.defer();
         leafletData.getMap('map').then(function(map) {
            $scope.map = map;
            map.invalidateSize();
            d.resolve(map);
        }, function(err) {

            d.reject(err);
        });
        return d.promise;

    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many tests, I finally installed the [cordova whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) and with it, everything is back to normal.

I really don't know yet Why there is this change concerning the whitelist recently. 
I'll keep you posted if I have other information concerning that change & impacts

Comment: Some [info here](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/15/cordova-android-4.0.0.html) that specifically states this change (in Major Changes)