# Ionic + Angular - How to avoid the "404 Not Found (from cache)" after POST request?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, post, http-status-code-404

this question is partly pointing to my previous question : 
[Ionic + Angular POST request return state 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122890/ionic-angular-post-request-return-state-404)

But i wasn't able to find working solution.

Problem is following:

if I do request from the mobile app running on the device i always get response 404:

```
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found (from cache)
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type:text/plain
Origin:file://
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; Lenovo Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
Request Payloadview source
{,…}
```

But if i tried the same request on the desktop using Postman plugin in the Chrome browser i always get response 200 with data what i need.

I thought that it was issue caused by Angular http method but in previous post i was noticed that is not true.

How can i avoid this please? Should i set some headers in HTML of the app, during the request or on the server side (PHP)?

Many thanks for any advice.

**EDIT:**

I tried also set cache:false by this way:

```
$http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : $scope.remoteUrl,
                data: postData,
                headers: headersData,
                cache: false,
                timeout: 10000
                // success response
            })
```

But without luck.

Comment: Have you tried `{cache: false}` ?

Comment: Hello, i just updated my question. Is cache attribute placed correctly in my request?

Comment: Might be a problem with your PHP server. Try `header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");` in PHP.

Comment: Still same, i need to avoid (from cache) during the request. So i think, that is no related with server.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

A [lot of people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124099/ionic-leaflet-cant-get-tiles-404-not-found-from-cache/30128353) are [experiencing that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122890/ionic-angular-post-request-return-state-404/30209484#30209484).

I just ran into the same problem. It seems it has to do with a new security policy in new versions of Cordova.

**Here's how I solved it:**

I installed [Cordova's whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) :

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Then, add your content policy in your `index.html` as a meta tag (using your own host or '*' for accepting all requests) :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' yourhost.com ws://localhost:35729 data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *;script-src 'self' localhost:35729 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';">
```

`default-src` is used for general requests; the `ws://localhost:35729` host is used for live-reload in `ionic serve`.

`script-src` is used for secure script execution

`unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-eval` are required in order for angular to work properly.

`data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com` is only used on iOS.

`self` means the current host of the `index.html` file.

> You'll have to add your own in order for your requests to work. Don't forget to add the protocol and the port if they're non-standard
>
> You can skip the meta tag if you don't want it, but you'll get a lot of warnings from the whitelist plugin.

More info on how to configure this in [the plugin's readme](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist).

Then rebuild your app, and it should work again.

Comment: Yes - this was exactly it. Beat my head around this for an hour. thanks!

Comment: THANK you so much !! works with Ionic3 + auth0 tutorial https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ionic3/

Answer (score 36):

Had a same problem, nothing helped, then i just removed the whitelist plugin:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

then renstalled it

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

then it worked

Comment: You mean `cordova plugin` I guess?

Comment: Works for me! It seems that we have to install Android SDK before install cordova-plugin-whitelist.

Comment: This worked for me too!  I had just updated Android Studio on my Mac and then ran into this issue.  Simply removing and re-adding the Whitelist plugin solved it

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I could solve it by adding the following plugin:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

Answer (score 3):

After many hours, I found one solution that worked:
run `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

In my case, I had already configured config.xml and index.html on origin, as mentioned here and elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with Firebase sign on my android device but I could login on the browser.

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-whitelist
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Used the above lines to resolve the issue.