# how to get the vector tile by Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles

During these days, I am obsessed by a big problem —— how to get the vector tile by Geoserver? I have looking for many docs and blogs, and there are some useful resource for the problem, the operation is very easy if step by step:
http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/dataadmin/vectortiles/index.html;

But after these operations, I still don't get success, i wonder to konw the reason, if you have some idea, please sharing with me, thanks for your kind~

ps:there is some message from console，maybe it's useful:
about gwc seeding:

10 一月 10:27:45 INFO [seed.SeedTask] - GWC Seeder Thread-4 completed (re)seeding layer cn:roads after 192 tiles and 2 seconds.

10 一月 10:27:45 INFO [seed.SeedTask] - GWC Seeder Thread-3 completed (re)seeding layer cn:roads after 80 tiles and 2 seconds.

10 一月 10:27:45 INFO [seed.GWCTask] - Thread group finished SEED task after 2.578 seconds

I don't have enough reputation, so I copy the message to here instead of sending a image, sorry

//*************************************************************************

I have already added the vector-tiles plugin,

and there are some errors when I request the tiles:

> http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/cite:DLZXX_2011_PL_10000@EPSG%3A4326@geojson/11/1673/891.geojson 404 (Not Found)

//the code to get vector tiles

```
var vectorTile = new ol.layer.VectorTile({

        //get source
        source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
            format:new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
                maxZoom:14
            }),
            tilePixelRatio:1,
            url:'/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/'+layerName
              +'@EPSG%3A4326@geojson/{z}/{x}/{y}.geojson'
        }),
        style:initStyle
    });

    map.addLayer(vectorTile);
```

Header of each Tile GET request

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encodin: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Cookie: JSESSIONID=9679B11893A04A0ACE21D49D93AB7CDC
Host: localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/23DPlatform/index.jsp
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
```

Header of response

```
Content-Disposition :inline; filename=geoserver-dispatch.text
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 13:01:09 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

//***************************************************************

Maybe you can read this question, there are some similar

> [Ionic / Leaflet - Can't get Tiles 404 Not Found (from cache)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124099/ionic-leaflet-cant-get-tiles-404-not-found-from-cache)

Comment: please add more details of your set up, did you add the vector-tiles plugin? what error do you see in the logs when you request tiles? Note: the above lines are INFOrmative not ERRORs,

Comment: @iant yes, sure. i have already added the vector-tiles plugin, and there is the source:http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/master/ext-latest/
there are some errors when i request the tiles: 
ol.js:428 GET http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/cite:DLZXX_2011_PL_10000@EPSG%3A4326@geojson/11/1673/892.geojson 404 (Not Found)

Comment: please edit the question with this information

Comment: sorry, this is my first time to ask question on stackoverflow, I have edited the question

Answer (score 4):

I have already got the vector tiles by geoserver and openLayers3.

1)The vector tiles in geoserver(GeoWebcache) are **created dynamically**, so you 
don't need to click the seeding button on GeoWebcache admin page;

2)The projection of your data is a very important param, the default projection in OL3 is EPSG:3857. **so you need to make sure the projections(layer,source,tilegrid) are same**;

*PS:I had written down the process on my blog:*

> http://www.cnblogs.com/escage/p/6387529.html

*sorry, it's Chinese blog, if you have any question about these topic, you can 
contact me with email:*

***ericliuneverlost@163.com***